# Start selenium-server on jenkins build step

Tags: php, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, codeception

**Desired result**

1. Start selenium server
2. Run tests
3. Stop selenium server

**What i've tried**

```
java -jar tests/selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedrive
```

The build gets stuck on this step

```
java -jar tests/selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedrive &
```

OR

```
nohup java -jar tests/selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedrive > log.txt &
```

It passes the start server step, but my test can't run because it cant connect to selenium server

** Update 1 **
It seems to be a issue with my VPS.
Even through ssh, the selenium server doesn't starts.

```
root@PIV:/usr/share/nginx/pivdev/tests# java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

**Output:**

```
21:53:08.857 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
21:53:08.911 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02
21:53:08.914 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-52-generic amd64
21:53:08.945 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
21:53:09.070 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Why downvote ? Would you care to explain how I can improve my question ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my setup.

The selenium server was stuck waiting to start because it was waiting for the system to generate random data at /dev/random.

For more information check my other question [Selenium standalone server not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707201/selenium-standalone-server-not-starting)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run selenium web driver testcases in jenkins, just go through the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e8I3A49ERc

Comment: Actually I just need to start the selenium server, the tests will run on codeception.