# Selenium standalone server not starting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running into trouble while starting selenium standalone server on my VPS

```
root@PIV:/usr/share/nginx/pivdev/tests# java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

**Output:**

```
21:53:08.857 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
21:53:08.911 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02
21:53:08.914 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-52-generic amd64
21:53:08.945 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
21:53:09.070 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
21:53:09.071 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
```

No more output after that.
Locally the same command works like like a charm. Any hint how to fix this issue ?

**Java**

```
root@PIV:/usr/share/nginx/pivdev/tests# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Update 1**

The service is not running on any port at all

Netstat output

```
root@PIV:~# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      898/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1247/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      974/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1247/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      496/vsftpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      898/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::35484                :::*                    LISTEN      2036/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50920                :::*                    LISTEN      2036/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2036/java
```

**Update 2**

Ok, the main issue here is that selenium server is getting stuck on startup, and I dont know why. I destroyed my VPS machine and started from scratch. The selenium server booted up once, after I stopped and started again the issue happened(And persists after reboot). Sometimes it doesnt works even on the first try.

I'm not sure if its either a java problem or selenium server problem or my VPS host problem.

Comment: which version is of your  standalone Selenium Server JAR?

Comment: @HelpingHands the JAR version is 2.41.0. The latest available on seleniumhq website

Comment: I mean 2.47.1 (the latest) and 2.41.0

Comment: You should keep all JARs version same..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Long short story:

Selenium uses /dev/random (don't know why, dont ask) and it was waiting for enough entropy to generate the random number.

**THE FIX**

Just add the parameter when starting selenium: `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom switch` and you're good to go

Comment: A DAY OF MY LIFE went away because of this s**t, and at the end- you saved me, my hero.
Seriously, thanks for that fix.

Answer (score 0):

When running on linux it is better to start selenium server with some capabilities provided similar to below:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/path/to/google-chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver -browser browserName=chrome platform=LINUX -port 4444
```

Also ,not sure if your local system is Linux.

Comment: My local system is linux, but still not working.. I'm updating my answer with the results.