# Unable to start Selenium Server on CentOS7

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any limitations to start Selenium Server on CentOS7? Followings are my environments. I was able to start it on CentOS6.5.

Worked

- CentOS6.5
- Kernel: 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
- java: 1.8.0_65
- Selenium Server: 2.47.1

  ```
  # java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar
  14:44:39.511 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
  14:44:39.580 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.65-b01
  14:44:39.581 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 amd64
  14:44:39.612 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
  14:44:39.769 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
  registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
  14:44:39.771 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
  registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
  14:44:39.771 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
  14:44:39.771 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
  14:44:39.935 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
  14:44:39.935 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
  ```

Didn't work

- CentOS7
- Kernel: 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
- java: Same version
- Selenium Server: Same version

  ```
  # java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar
  05:47:08.911 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
  05:47:08.988 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.65-b01
  05:47:08.988 INFO - OS: Linux 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 amd64
  05:47:09.015 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
  05:47:09.145 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
  registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
  05:47:09.146 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
  registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
  05:47:09.146 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
  05:47:09.146 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
  ```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer can help. Please see [Selenium standalone server not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707201/selenium-standalone-server-not-starting).

In short: Just add the parameter when starting selenium: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom switch and you're good to go